# Eloquent Users in Same Group

Tags: php, eloquent

I have the usual users, groups and group_user tables. I know the raw SQL that I want:

```
SELECT group_user.group_id, users.* FROM users
INNER JOIN group_user ON users.id = group_user.user_id
WHERE group_user.group_id IN
(SELECT group_id FROM group_user WHERE user_id=?)
ORDER BY group_user.group_id;
```

where ? is replaced current user's id.

but, I want to use Eloquent (outside of laravel) for this. I have tried using a User model with a groups method

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\Smawt\User\Group');
}
```

and a Membership model with a users method

```
public function users($group_id) {
    return $this->where('group_id', '=', $group_id)->get();
}
```

and then I loop through the groups and then loop through all its members. Finally, I append all the data to get one $users object at the end, to pass through to my view.

```
$thisMembership = new Membership;
$myGroups = $app->auth->groups;

$users = [];

foreach ($myGroups as $myGroup) {

    foreach ($thisMembership->users($myGroup->id) as $myUser) {

        $thisUser = $app->user->where('id', '=', $myUser->user_id)->first();
        $thisUser->group_id = $myGroup->id;

        array_push($users, $thisUser);
    }
}
```

Then in my view I loop through my $users as normal. Although this method works, it will not be very efficient as I am unable to work out how to use Eager Loading with it.

Is there a simpler more 'Eloquent' way of getting an object of users who are in the same group as the current user? I don't want just want a list, or an array, as I want to use the other methods defined in my user model.

Comment: A bit off topic, but your `SQL` `where` clause if overly complicated. Just write `where users.user_id = ?`. Because of your `inner join` condition this yields the same results. It will make your Eloquent implementation easier as well.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't see how they are equivalent, as I am trying to find users in the same groups as the current user, who may belong to many groups.

Comment: Indeed, and that is what you will find as well with the simplified query. First you limit the records from the *users* table by your current user's id. This results in just one *users* record being retained, and then you join in the  table user_groups, requiring that the records from there have the same **user_id** as the one in the selected *users* record, which happens to be your current user's id. From those matching records you will get the groups this user belongs to.

Comment: I may just be having a bad day, but will that not just give me the group ids, but not the other users who also belong to that group?

Comment: Indeed, and I missed the point that you wanted to list the other users in those groups. Please ignore my previous statements, your query is fine then!

Answer (score 0):

The `Eloquent` way for the relationship and use of it:

```
Tables: users, groups
Models: User   Group 
Pivot Table: group_user (id, user_id, group_id)
```

In User Model:

```
public function groups()
{
    // pivot table name and related field
    // names are optional here in this case
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group');
}
```

In Group Model:

```
public function users()
{
    // pivot table name and related field
    // names are optional here in this case
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

Use Case (Example):

```
$usersWithGroup = User::with('groups')->find(1); // or get()
$groupWithUsers = Group::with('users')->find(1); // or get()
```

For more information check [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) section on documentation.

### Update:

If user belongsto any group

```
$usersWithGroup = User::has('groups')->with('groups')->find(1);
```

Also using if a user belongs to specific group:

```
$someGroup = 'general';
$usersWithGroup = User::whereHas('groups', function($q) use($someGroup) {
    $q->where('group_name', $someGroup);
})
->with('groups')->find(1);
```

Comment: What am I missing here? If I loop through each group, then I need to test whether my current user is in that group, then I need to get all of the other users of that group. So I could do foreach on the ($groupWithUsers->all() as $thisGroup), but then I still need to do something like if ( $thisGroup->where('user_id', '=', $currentUserId)->get() ) to check whether this is a group that my current user belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to construct the following Eloquent query, although I am not sure this is the 'best' way:

```
$users = User::join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
        ->whereIn('group_user.group_id', function($query) {
            $query->select('group_id')
                  ->from('group_user')
                  ->where('group_user.user_id', '=', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        })->orderBy('group_id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```